# Counterexample for Jensen's inequality for rank one convex function

Tags: jensen-inequality

We all know the Jensen's inequality is for all probability measures $\mu$ and all convex $h:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ it holds that
\begin{equation}
h\left(\int Xd\mu(X)\right)\leq \int h(X)d\mu(X).
\end{equation}
But the the definition of laminate is for rank-one convex function $h$, Jensen's inequality holds. I want to find a example that a probability measure for rank-one convex function such that Jensen's inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: What is a rank one convex function?

Comment: The definition of rank-one convex function is: for every $\xi,\eta\in M^{m\times n}$, with $\mathrm{rank}(\xi-\eta)\leq 1$ and every $\lambda\in (0,1)$, $f:M^{m\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is called rank-one convex function if satisfying
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda\xi+(1-\lambda)\eta)\leq \lambda f(\xi)+(1-\lambda)f(\eta).
\end{equation}